# What does mean by the $\text{stable}$ action of a Galois group $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ on a set $X$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

What does mean by the $\text{stable}$ action of a Galois group $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ on a set $X$?

i.e., when we say an action of the Galois group is $\text{stable}$ ?

Please explain it and perhaps if possible with an example.

Comment: Do you know what a stable group action is? Without considering the Galois group?

Comment: Usually if you have a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, you say that $Y\subseteq X$ is stable if $G\cdot Y \subseteq Y$.

Comment: @DonThousand, Yes I know stable group action? Oh I got it